# How to select a enums based on the input

Tags: java, enums

I create different enums and I want to use them based on the input value. Like if the input value is 1, then I will use the first enum and I will use the second enum if the input is 2.The code is like:

```
for (ENUM_ONE enumOne: ENUM_ONE.values()) {
    ENUM_ONE Obj = ((ENUM_ONE) enumOne);
    System.out.println(Obj.getName());
}
```

Could I define a variable to represent the different enums? It's like

```
if(input == 1){
    enum = ENUM_ONE;
}else{
    enum = ENUM_TWO;
}

for (enum enumOne: enum .values()) {
        enum Obj = ((enum) enumOne);
        System.out.println(Obj.getName());
    }
```

Is there have some way to change the `ENUM_ONE` to `ENUM_TWO` so that there don't need to write the similar `for()` every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of a way (or any reason) to try and change the name of an `enum`. If you are looking to change something based on user input, that is precisely the type of decision making that `if/then/else` statements were made for...

Comment: Thank you Zephyr, I would like to know if there was a way to define a variable to represent the different enums? I have updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an parameter to the enum that represents something (like an Integer). Then iterate the enum values and find the one that actually contain that value.

Alternatively you can create a Map for fast enum lookup.

Check following link to find out more: https://www.google.pl/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-customized-value-java/amp/